# Find $\int x^2 d(x^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration

Here is my problem:
$$I = \int x^2 d(x^2)$$

I used a $u = x^2$ substitution
$$\frac{d(x^2)}{du} = 1$$
$$d(x^2) = du$$

Putting that into I,
$$I = \int u du$$
$$I = \frac{u^2}{2}$$
$$I = \frac{x^4}{2} + C$$

However I think my working out might be incorrect, intuitively I was expecting I to have an x to the power of 3.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: What you have done is correct if you add a constant of integration.

Comment: The classic forgot the plus C mistake, thanks for your help

Comment: How do we know $d(x^2) = 2x dx$ ?

Comment: @DanielGilbert The derivative of $f(x)=x^2$ with respect to $x$ is $2x$, so the differential of $x^2$ at $x$, i.e. $df(x)$ equals $f'(x)\,dx = 2x\,dx$. You can take it as a definition of differential. You can generalise to integrals of $x^n\,d(x^n)$: the differential of $x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}\,dx$, then integrating you have $\int nx^{2n-1}\,dx = (1/2)x^{2n}+\text{const}$.

Comment: @DanielGilbert $\mbox{d} g(x) = g'(x)\,\mbox{d}x$; now take $g(x)=x^2$.

Answer (score 8):

What you did was correct. To see this, we can calculate $I$ more explicitly using $d(x^2)=2x\,dx$, then $$I=\int x^2 d(x^2)=\int 2x^3 dx=\frac{x^4}{2}+C$$